# Fast ways to multiply small matrices?

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization, numpy

Context: I'm trying to optimize a portfolio of assets for some arbitrary goal. Currently, I'm multiplying the matrix representing the different assets with the matrix representing the weights (taken from a cartesian product). Thereafter, each portfolio's performance is evaluated to find the optimal weights.

Unfortunately, this has been proven to be extremely time consuming for anything other than very small portfolios.

Question:
What are some fas ways to multiply relatively small matrices such as [500 x 100][100 x 1] billions of times?

What are some good libraries?

Is there any way to accelerate it with a CUDA-enabled GPU?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839539/how-to-get-faster-code-than-numpy-dot-for-matrix-multiplication

Comment: Also https://www.benjaminjohnston.com.au/matmul